# How do I switch div's without messing it up?

Tags: html, shopify

I would like to put the Categories sections above the Recent Posts section without screwing it up but I'm having trouble. Any suggestions?

```
 <div align="center"> 
  <h3>Recent Articles</h3> </div>
  <ul id="posts">
    {% for article in blog.articles  %}
    <li><a href="{{article.url}}">{{ article.title }}</a>
      <p>{{ article.published_at | date: "%b %d %Y" }}</p>
      {{ article.excerpt_or_content }}
      <p>{{ article.content | strip_html | truncate: 100 }}</p>
    </li>
    {% endfor %} 
    <div align="center"> 
      <h3 style="margin: 20px 0">Categories</h3> </div>
    {% for tag in blog.all_tags %}
    <li class="tags">
      <a href="{{ shop.url}}/blogs/{{ blog.handle }}/tagged/{{ tag | handleize }}">{{ tag }}</a>
    </li>


    {% endfor %} 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the tags `{% %}` which are most likely for a Shopify website -- they must be moved with the html blocks. The following code will work:

```
<div align="center"><h3>Categories</h3></div>
<ul id="posts">
    {% for tag in blog.all_tags %}
    <li class="tags">
      <a href="{{ shop.url}}/blogs/{{ blog.handle }}/tagged/{{ tag | handleize }}">{{ tag }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %} 

    <div align="center"><h3 style="margin: 20px 0">Recent Articles</h3></div>
    {% for article in blog.articles  %}
    <li><a href="{{article.url}}">{{ article.title }}</a>
      <p>{{ article.published_at | date: "%b %d %Y" }}</p>
      {{ article.excerpt_or_content }}
      <p>{{ article.content | strip_html | truncate: 100 }}</p>
    </li>
    {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

Your code given also had an extra `</div>` tag at the end, which is not needed in this context so I removed it.

Comment: Try adding back the extra `</div>` tag to the end of the above code. If this doesn't fix it, the issue may be in the CSS styles applied.